# How to use two IDs from JS?

Tags: javascript

On my page with payment I need two inputs with total payment value:
- one that the client can see
- another one which is hidden.

I wrote a code which pass price of every element to the input when a client check a box with a product they want to pay for, but it works only with the one input.

I was trying to use different options (like getElementsByName and getElementsByClassName) but I am learning JS now and I have no idea how to solve this problem. :(

```
function select(selector, parent){
  return Array.from((parent||document).querySelectorAll(selector));  
}

var inputs = select('.sum'),
    **totalElement = document.getElementById('payment-total');**

function sumUpdate(){
  totalElement.value = inputs.reduce(function(result, input){
    return result + (input.checked ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0);
  }, 0).toFixed(0);
}
```

WHAT I TRIED:

```
var inputs = select('.sum'),
        **totalElement = document.getElementsByName('payment-total')[0][1];**

var inputs = select('.sum'),
            **totalElement = document.getElementsByName('payment-total, payment-total2')[0][1];**

var inputs = select('.sum'),
                **totalElement = document.getElementsByName('payment-total).getElementsByName('payment-totalTwo);**
```

Comment: Would you provide your markup, or at least parts of HTML  related to shopping card. that you try to get query over them.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Provided you have an element with `id="payment-total"`, and provided your code is running when the elements are already in the DOM (put the `script` at the end of `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag), that should be fine. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Ah, okay, your code only updates one element and you've said you want to update two.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, you want to put the computed value in both the `id="payment-total"` element and the `id="payment-total2"` element.

If so, just do what you've already done for `payment-total`, but for `payment-total2` as well, see `***` comments:

```
var inputs = select('.sum'),
    totalElement = document.getElementById('payment-total'),
    totalElement2 = document.getElementById('payment-total2'); // ***

function sumUpdate(){
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---- ***
  totalElement2.value = totalElement.value = inputs.reduce(function(result, input){
    return result + (input.checked ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0);
  }, 0).toFixed(0);
}
```

I don't immediately see the reason for having both a visible and a hidden input, but if you need that for some reason, that's how you'd do it.

If it got to the point there were three or more elements you wanted to update, I'd probably give them all a class and select them the way you've selected your `.sum` elements, then compute the total once and assign it to all of them in a loop. But for just two, repeating the lookup and assignment seems fine.